# AllowHtml Not Working - But Works Fine With Different Model/Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have two very similar processes, both requiring HTML input and the AllowHtml attribute... One process creates an HTML Email, while the other creates an Update Message to display to logged in users.

The AllowHtml Attribute is working fine when creating the Emails but when I try to create an Update Message it throws the 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value...' error.

**What would cause AllowHtml to work in for one and not the other?**

I've poured over all of my code and can't figure out what is different between the two that could cause this problem.

---

**Here is my code in the Email Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new EmailBlast());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmailBlast Email)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var EmailID = _emailblasts.Create(Email);
    }
    return View(Email);
}
```

**And here is the Email model:**

```
public class EmailBlast
{
    public decimal EmailID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Subject")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Subject Too Long")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Include a Message")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string HTMLBody { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**Here is my code in the Update Messages Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new CreateUpdateMessage());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUpdateMessage message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var Message = _updatemessages.Create(message);
        return RedirectToAction("View", new { id = Message.ID });
    }
    return View(message);
}
```

**And the Update Message model:**

```
public class CreateUpdateMessage
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Subject")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Subject Too Long")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Include a Message")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

---

Ok, so I figured out the problem... "Message" must be a reserved parameter or something because I changed CreateUpdateMessage.Message to "MessageHTML" and everything works fine now.

```
public class CreateUpdateMessage
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Subject")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Subject Too Long")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Include a Message")]
    [AllowHtml]
--> public string MessageHTML { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This question is SOLVED... Wouldn't let me answer my own question though.

Answer (score 0):

For others having a similar problem, try adding `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in the `<system.web>` section of your web.config.

Comment: Don't do this as it reduces the security of your site globally.